# How to download files using multer-sftp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, multer

I have this code, but surfing the web, i cannot found some way to download a file from the remote server. I'm able to upload the files in the remote server but I don't have any idea how download from there.

```
var storage = sftpStorage({
  sftp: {
    host: '171.16.....',
    port: xxxx,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, 'uploads')
   },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

This is the route to upload the files: (Works great!)

```
router.post('/upload-image', upload.single('file'), listarController.uploadImage);
```

This is the route to download the files - locally: (Searching a method...)

```
router.get('/get-file/:file', listarController.getFile);
```

The method to download locally:

```
controller.getFile = (req, res) => {
    var file = req.params.file;
    var path_file = './uploads/' + file;
    fs.exists(path_file, (exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            return res.sendFile(path.resolve(path_file))
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send({
                message: "The image doesn't exist."
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Some suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following libraries:
1. multer-sftp: To upload the files.
2. ftp: To download and rename the files.